# MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm) always throwing NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, hash, jce

I'm creating a simple password vault/generator, and right now I'm working on the vault portion of my code, and am writing code for encrypting passwords. I'm using MessageDigest.

However when I try to choose an algorithm it always throws a NoSuchAlgorithmException. I'm trying to use SHA-1 or SHA-256. I've looked everywhere and I can't find a solution. EDIT: I forgot to mention I've tried "SHA-1", "SHA-256", and "MD5". None work.

My method:

```
private static String generateHash(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    messageDigest.update(input.getBytes());
    String encryptedString = new String(messageDigest.digest());
    System.out.println("encryptedString :: " + encryptedString);
    return encryptedString;
}
```

(I'm only printing out encryptedString for debugging purposes)

I'm using JDK 1.8.0_91, and IntelliJ IDEA 1.5.0.2.

**EDIT:** So I figured out what was wrong. Instead of using `throws NoSuchAlgorithmException`, I need to put my code into a try/catch block catching `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. I don't know why but it fixed my issue.

Comment: NB: The bytes returned by `digest()` are raw binary data not suitable for converting into a `String`. If you want a string you ought to hex encode them.

Comment: I'm still rather new to hashing, and I got mixed up quite a bit. I'm trying to use SHA-256, but SHA-1, SHA-256, and MD5 won't work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please run the following code to get a list of algorithms and security providers. http://pastebin.com/sQ2V2152

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle's documentation on the MessageDigest class:

> Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard MessageDigest algorithms:
>
> MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256

Oracle's JVM supports MD2, MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512

Comment: This still gives me an error, oddly enough. I've tried MD5 and SHA-256 too. I'll update my question. I also forgot to edit my code to the original state it was in.

Comment: Not relevant to this Q, but Oracle Java 8 adds SHA-224. And also the OID-form aliases for all implemented SHA*, but those are aliases not distinct algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

SHA-128 which you mentioned in your original unedited question is not supported. The supported Message Digest algorithms are given in the [Standard Names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest) document.

NB a message digest does not produce an 'encrypted string'.